# Results not factoring into excel vba spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, invoice, accounting

(EDITED, Issue partly resolved, see comments) I'm new to VBA so this might be tedious but: I'm having some issues with code I've written to try to add discounts to an invoice. I have it so that if a 1 is written in a certain row under one discount column in 'Org List', that discount number is reflected in the cost column of 'QuickCalcs', for the items associated with the organization having the discount. I've tested it to make sure the if statements are working correctly, and they are. The calculations are also correct, but for some reason these values aren't replacing the original costs calculated by multiplying quantity and rate. It seems the amount.value = amount.value - dis1 line and the others like it aren't working, or maybe I'm misunderstanding it. When I was testing, I had amount.value appear in another empty cell and the correct value showed, but it doesn't seem to be working when entering it into a cell with a preexisting amount for some reason, though this may not be the issue. How would you recommend I fix this so that the correct discounted amounts are reflected in the cost column (QuickCalcs, col L)? My code is below. Thank you!!

```
Sub Discounts()
    Dim orgnameB    As Range
    Dim orgListB    As Range
    Set orgListB = Worksheets("Org List").Range("B3:B23")
    Dim siteTC      As Range
    Dim TCsites     As Range
    Set TCsites = Worksheets("TC Site Report").Range("B2:B23")
    Dim itemDescr   As Range
    Dim quickcalcsI As Range
    Set quickcalcsI = Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Range("I2:I23")
    
    ' Amount Calculation
    Dim amount      As Range
    Dim rateval     As Range
    Dim qtyval      As Range
    Dim total       As Double
    Dim dis1        As Integer
    Dim dis2        As Integer
    Dim dis3        As Integer
    Dim dis4        As Integer
    Dim dis5        As Integer
    Dim dis6        As Integer
    
    For Each orgnameB In orgListB
        If IsEmpty(orgnameB) = TRUE Then
            Exit For
        End If
        For Each siteTC In TCsites
            For Each itemDescr In quickcalcsI
                Set amount =     Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Cells(itemDescr.row, "L")
                Set rateval = Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Cells(itemDescr.row, "K")
                Set qtyval = Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Cells(itemDescr.row, "J")
                amount.Value = rateval.Value * qtyval.Value
                total = amount.Value
                
                If Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "I").Value = 1 Or Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "K").Value = 1 Or Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "J").Value = 1 Then
                    ' If discount : if orgnameB.row, colI,J, or K = 1, apply discount
                    
                    If itemDescr.Value = siteTC.Value Then
                        
                        'If current item in quickcalcs = item in TC Site Report
                        If Worksheets("TC Site Report").Cells(siteTC.row, "D") = orgnameB.Value And Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Cells(itemDescr.row, "H") <> "Annual Fee" Then
                            'If current item in quickcalcs is associated with that org
                            If Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "I") = 1 Then
                                percentoff1 = Worksheets("Org List").Cells(2, "I").Value / 100
                                dis1 = total * (percentoff1)
                                amount.Value = amount.Value - dis1
                            End If
                            If Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "J") = 1 Then
                                percentoff2 = Worksheets("Org List").Cells(2, "I").Value / 100
                                dis2 = total * (percentoff2)
                                amount.Value = amount.Value - dis2
                            End If
                            If Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "K") = 1 Then
                                percentoff3 = Worksheets("Org List").Cells(2, "I").Value / 100
                                dis3 = total * (percentoff3)
                                amount.Value = amount.Value - dis3
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```

[Ranges Worked with, QuickCalcs Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Hjn.png)

[Ranges Worked with, TC Site Report Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFGxD.png)

[Ranges Worked with, Org List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elEyP.png)

Comment: You are setting `amount.Value = rateval.Value * qtyval.Value` multiple times as you loop through `orgListB` and `TCsites` so any discounted value is probably being overwritten by the next iteration of  `orgListB / TCsites`. I suspect you need to change the loop nesting so that `For Each itemDescr In quickcalcsI` is the top level.

Comment: I tried doing that but still got the same results...now I'm using a separate for loop to calculate the simple total and then a separate one to add the discount and it's still not working. Only the simple total appears, even if the second set of for loops is run through and the discounts are calculated correctly. Any advice?

Comment: I'll post the code I have, see if it works.

Comment: I looked into testing my code a little further and it seems a main issue might be with the 'percentoff1' variable. I added these lines of testing to the dis1 if statement:  Dim percentoff1 As Long
                    percentoff1 = Worksheets("Org List").Cells(2, "I").Value
                    Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Range("C12") = percentoff1
                    percentoff1 = percentoff1 / 100
                    Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Range("C13") = percentoff1. The percentoff1 value / 100 goes straight to 0.00 instead of 0.1.

Comment: if you define it as Long that is an integer value, use `Dim percentoff1 As Single` or `Double`

Comment: Thank you! Did that and that fixed that issue! Now I'm getting something strange where only the final value in the range is discounted, but twice (10% is taken off total twice). But none of the other numbers change.

Comment: Edit your post with the code you are now using.

Comment: I've fixed the doubled discounts but still have the final value issue. Only the final item has the discount.

Comment: I've also noticed that now items with the name "Annual Fee" are given a discount, despite the if statement for the discount specifying that the item description should not be 'annual fee' for a discount to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-arranging the nesting of the loops so that `Worksheets("QuickCalcs")` is only scanned once. Is `percentoff` alway `wsOrg.Cells(2, "I").Value` even if for example `wsOrg.Cells(r2, "J") = 1` ?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Discounts()

    Dim wsOrg As Worksheet, orgnameB As Range, orgListB As Range
    Set wsOrg = Worksheets("Org List")
    Set orgListB = wsOrg.Range("B3:B23")

    Dim wsSite As Worksheet, siteTC As Range, TCsites As Range
    Set wsSite = Worksheets("TC Site Report")
    Set TCsites = wsSite.Range("B2:B23")

    Dim wsCalc As Worksheet, itemDescr As Range, quickcalcsI As Range
    Set wsCalc = Worksheets("QuickCalcs")
    Set quickcalcsI = wsCalc.Range("I2:I23")

    ' Amount Calculation
    Dim amount As Range, rateval As Range, qtyval As Range
    Dim total, percentoff, dis
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, r3 As Long

    For Each itemDescr In quickcalcsI
        r1 = itemDescr.Row

        With Worksheets("QuickCalcs")
            Set amount = .Cells(r1, "L")
            Set rateval = .Cells(r1, "K")
            Set qtyval = .Cells(r1, "J")
            amount.Value = rateval.Value * qtyval.Value
            total = amount.Value
        End With

        For Each orgnameB In orgListB
            If IsEmpty(orgnameB) = True Then
                Exit For
            End If
            r2 = orgnameB.Row

            ' If discount : if orgnameB.row, colI,J, or K = 1, apply discount
            If wsOrg.Cells(r2, "I").Value = 1 _
                Or wsOrg.Cells(r2, "K").Value = 1 _
                Or wsOrg.Cells(r2, "J").Value = 1 Then

                For Each siteTC In TCsites
                     
                    If itemDescr.Value = siteTC.Value Then
                        r3 = siteTC.Row
                            'If current item in quickcalcs = item in TC Site Report
                        If wsSite.Cells(r3, "D") = orgnameB.Value _
                           And wsCalc.Cells(r1, "H") <> "Annual Fee" Then

                            'If current item in quickcalcs is associated with that org
                            If wsOrg.Cells(r2, "I") = 1 Then
                                percentoff = wsOrg.Cells(2, "I").Value / 100
                                dis = total * percentoff
                                amount.Value = amount.Value - dis
                            End If
                            If wsOrg.Cells(r2, "J") = 1 Then
                                percentoff = wsOrg.Cells(2, "I").Value / 100
                                dis = total * percentoff
                                amount.Value = amount.Value - dis
                            End If
                            If wsOrg.Cells(r2, "K") = 1 Then
                                percentoff = wsOrg.Cells(2, "I").Value / 100
                                dis = total * percentoff
                                amount.Value = amount.Value - dis
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I kept the percentoff1 declaration out of the for loops and now I don't get the doubled discount error I was getting before. I'm still having the same issue I mentioned in the comments above where only the last item in the range of items in col I of QuickCalcs is discounted. Do you know why this might be? Thank you so much for your time! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Cblue Are any of the cells in `Worksheets("Org List").Range("B3:B23")` empty ?

Comment: I've also noticed that now items with the name "Annual Fee" are given a discount, despite the if statement for the discount specifying that the item description should not be 'annual fee' for a discount to be applied.

Comment: there are empty cells but those signify the end of the information on the tab. There are no empty cells between data points.

Comment: @Cblue `<> "Annual Fee"` is case sensitive so `annual fee` would not work. Check no trailing spaces like "Annual Fee " or change code to `LCase(Trim(wsCalc.Cells(r1, "H"))) <> "annual fee" Then`. If you can post some screen shots of the ranges that would help.

Comment: Yes, I have only "Annual Fee" written, with no extra spaces. I'll add some screenshots of the ranges.

Comment: The screenshot links are available above now. The one of the QuickCalcs tab shows how the 'annual fee' item is the only one with 10% off. I played with the range and it seems as if whichever item is the last in the range gets 10% off, regardless of its 'item name'. Annual Fee should not be able to get 10% off, the if statement should block it. I've also tried not using <> "Annual Fee" and using = "Site" instead because I have been having issues with does not equal but that doesn't make a difference either.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I added the trim suggestion you posted, it didn't work for "Annual Fee" but when I switched it to = "Site" it worked. Thank you! Now annual fee is not getting 10% off, so now none of the items have discounts (as it is the last item in the range)

Answer (score 0):

Using triple nested loops is not really a scalable solution and is difficult to debug with single steps (F8). A better way would be to directly locate the matching rows on the other sheets using [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find).  For example

```vb
Sub Discount2()

    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim wsOrg As Worksheet, orgnameB As Range, orgListB As Range
    Set wsOrg = Worksheets("Org List")
    iLastRow = wsOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set orgListB = wsOrg.Range("B3:B" & iLastRow)

    Dim wsSite As Worksheet, siteTC As Range, TCsites As Range
    Set wsSite = Worksheets("TC Site Report")
    iLastRow = wsSite.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set TCsites = wsSite.Range("B2:B" & iLastRow)

    Dim wsCalc As Worksheet, itemDescr As Range, quickcalcsI As Range
    Set wsCalc = Worksheets("QuickCalcs")
    iLastRow = wsCalc.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Set quickcalcsI = wsCalc.Range("I2:I" & iLastRow)

    Dim amount As Range, rateval As Range, qtyval As Range
    Dim rng As Range, org As String, dis As Single
    Dim r As Long, n As Long

    ' scan down sheet
    For Each itemDescr In quickcalcsI

        Set amount = Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Cells(itemDescr.Row, "L")
        Set rateval = Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Cells(itemDescr.Row, "K")
        Set qtyval = Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Cells(itemDescr.Row, "J")
        amount.Value = rateval.Value * qtyval.Value
        dis = 0

        ' find org for site
        Set rng = TCsites.Find(itemDescr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Site '" & itemDescr & "' not found", vbExclamation, "Row " & itemDescr.Row
        Else
            org = rng.Offset(, 2) ' col d
            ' Find discount for org
            Set rng = orgListB.Find(org, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Org '" & org & "' not found", vbExclamation, "Row " & itemDescr.Row
            Else
                r = rng.Row
                If wsOrg.Cells(r, "I") = 1 Then
                    dis = wsOrg.Cells(2, "I")
                ElseIf wsOrg.Cells(r, "J") = 1 Then
                    dis = wsOrg.Cells(2, "J")
                ElseIf wsOrg.Cells(r, "K") = 1 Then
                    dis = wsOrg.Cells(2, "K")
                End If
            End If
        End If

        ' apply discount
        If dis > 0 Then
            amount.Value = amount.Value * (100 - dis) / 100
            'amount.Interior.Color = vbYellow ' use to debug
            n = n + 1
        Else
            'amount.Interior.Color = vbWhite ' use to debug
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox n & " rows  discounted", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is very helpful. I'm getting a strange run time error from one of the lines of your code. The line "iLastRow = wsOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(x1Up).row" is getting an "application defined or object defined error" and I'm not sure why as I copied it directly and, looking at other answers on boards that have asked similar questions, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it... Do you know why it might be throwing this error?

Comment: @CBlue Don't know why you get that error, is code in same workbook as data ? What version of Excel, and OS ? Change line to `iLastRow =4` and see if there are any more errors.

Comment: yes it's the same workbook as the data. Changing the line to isLastRow = 4 does resolve the issue for that line, but then the next isLastRow = etc. line causes the same issue. I'm using Version 2105 (Build 14026.20308 Click-to-Run).

Comment: @CBlue I don't get these errors so you will have to debug them yourself. Assign an appropriate number to the others  2 lines. In the immediate window enter `debug.Print rows.Count, xlUp` you should get `1048576      -4162`